# Angular2 webpack html files

Tags: angular

When compiling for production the dist folder won't contain bundled html file i've also looked for them in the js files. I use the default webpack config from angular site and it seem like it should bundle for html files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install copy-webpack-plugin:

   npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin
2. Add to your webpack.common.js:

   var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
3. Add to your webpack.common.js inside plugins[]:

   new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'your_html_location', to: 'location_in_dist_folder' }

   ])
4. run npm run build